# What are Pros and Cons for using PSD formats?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format

What are Pros and Cons for using PSD formats?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really nearly impossible to answer unless the *context* of the file is known. PSD may be great for one use and horrible for another.

Comment: Why is this a gcse question its on the curriculum

Comment: Is there any advantage of using PSDT over PSD?

Answer (score 5):

**Pros:**

- Utilize all of Photoshop's features (retain adjustment layers, masks, shapes, clipping paths, layer styles, blending modes, smart objects).
- Tight integration between Adobe products, you can directly import a Photoshop file into Illustrator, InDesign, etc.
- Open saved file with layers.
- Useful if you need to maintain transparency.
- You can save 16-bits-per-channel and high dynamic range (HDR) 32-bits-per-channel images as PSD files.

**Cons:**

- Large file size.
- PSD is proprietary to Adobe. So it is not widely supported by other apps like TIFF is.